# Get Array with json without _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]

Tags: jquery, ajax, chart.js

I have a problem to load chartjs. 
I need get an array like : ["5000", "14000", "10000"]

but, I get: ["5000", "14000", "10000", _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]

This is my ajax response :

```
    {0: {status: 2},…}
    0: {status: 2}
    status: 2
    EGRESOS: [{Egreso: "5000", MES: "JUNE"}, {Egreso: "14000", MES: "APRIL"}, {Egreso: "10000", MES: "MAY"}]
    0: {Egreso: "5000", MES: "JUNE"}
    1: {Egreso: "14000", MES: "APRIL"}
    2: {Egreso: "10000", MES: "MAY"}
    INGRESOS: [{Ingreso: "34700", MES: "JUNE"}, {Ingreso: "4000", MES: "APRIL"}, {Ingreso: "5000", MES: "MAY"}]
    0: {Ingreso: "34700", MES: "JUNE"}
    1: {Ingreso: "4000", MES: "APRIL"}
    2: {Ingreso: "5000", MES: "MAY"}
```

my GLOBAL array:

```
 var dataEgresos = [];
```

code to output:

```
    var datosEgresos = response.EGRESOS;
    jQuery(datosEgresos).each(function(i, item){
    dataEgresos.push(item.Egreso);
     });
```

console result:

```
    console.log(dataEgresos);
```

prints:

```
    ["5000", "14000", "10000", _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]
```

that array is no valid chartjs dataset show graphics

**UPDATE:**

CHARTJS CODE:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labelMes,
                        datasets: [{
                                label: 'Egresos',
                                data: dataEgresos,
                                borderWidth: 2,
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(254,86,83,.7)',
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                borderColor: 'transparent',
                                pointBorderWidth: 0,
                                pointRadius: 3.5,
                                pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(254,86,83,.8)',
    }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    // display: false,
                                    drawBorder: false,
                                    color: '#f2f2f2',
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    stepSize: 1500,
                                    callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                        return '$' + value;
                                    }
                                }
      }],
                            xAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: false,
                                    tickMarkLength: 15,
                                }
      }]
                        },
                        tooltips: {

                            titleFontSize: 10,
                            bodyFontSize: 10
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Where do you make the ajax call?

Comment: last of the document.

Comment: Without knowing more I would assume you have a function that creates the chart, then after you make the ajax call you update it with the data in the `complete` part. Is that where you console.log? It would be helpful if you show the ajax call and how you build the chart.

Comment: $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ruta + "ajax/homeAjax.php",

        data: 'accion=' + accion+"&parametro="+parametro,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (objeto) {

            $("#loader").html("Cargando datos...");

        },
        success: function (response) {
                var canE = Object.keys(response.EGRESOS).length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < canI; i++) {
                  
                        dataEgresos.push(response.EGRESOS[i].Egreso);

                    }
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only remove the global array and I declare the array into function, problem resolved.